# How to reference a variable containing plus sign?

Tags: r, lm

The dataset `blood_storage` from the package [medicaldata](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/medicaldata/medicaldata.pdf) contains a variable `BN+`. How can I enter that variable *as is* in a model's formula? The following code will cause an error:

```
lm(TimeToRecurrence ~ RBC.Age.Group + Median.RBC.Age + Age + AA + FamHx + PVol + TVol + T.Stage +
                bGS + BN+ + OrganConfined, data=blood_storage)
```

Is there a workaround of the variable must be renamed to remove the `+` sign?

Comment: Use backticks `... + \`BN+\` + ...`.

Comment: Thanks so much @Ritchie. I kept forgetting that trick.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is the same for variables that have spaces in them. Use backticks.

```
lm(TimeToRecurrence ~ RBC.Age.Group + Median.RBC.Age + Age + AA + FamHx + PVol + TVol + T.Stage + bGS + `BN+` + OrganConfined, data=blood_storage)
```